# IBM Bluemix Apache Spark Resource Manager

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

Reading the official documentation I couldn't directly see what Resource Manager(Spark, Mesos, YARN) or how the Apache Spark managed service is currently setup(it only says you can provision up to 30 executors with no machine/cluster details).

Does anybody know what the Resource Manager of IBM's Spark service is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Bluemix Spark Service uses the Ego resource manager from Platform Symphony in an integrated environment.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSMK_7.1.0/management_sym/yarn_resource_management.html

For now, users cannot opt to select a type of resource manager, since the Spark service is a fully managed service.